# Pendência ao adicionar um item ao Menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Olá, saudações!
Estou com um problema ao adicionar um novo item ao menu Wordpress. O novo item a ser selecciona vem escrito Pendente e nunca muda.
Não sei o que se passa e o que fazer para solucionar.

Agradeceria se me puderem ajudar. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A página que eu desejo adicionar é esta que mostro abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não da para entender, se possível coloque imagens ou código para ficar mais claro

Comment: Anderson, o que acontece é que eu tenho adicionado novas páginas ao menu do meu projecto wordpress, mas criei uma novo e ao adicioná-lo ao menu, vem pendente e nunca adiciona esta página.

Comment: Já postei as imagens, Anderson. Agradeceria se me puder ajudar.

Comment: Legal, Bem mais claro haha @Constantino Faz o seguinte, é só essa página que está assim ou são todas?

Comment: Tentei criar mais uma para ver se o problema estivesse só nela, não funcionou. Tentei adicionar uma das já existentes também não funcionou, Anderson.

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo o Tema? Ou é tema ja feito? Você ja tem uma noção de wordpress? De uma olhada em páginas para ver se elas estão publicadas e visiveis

Comment: Estou a usar o tema ColorMag já existente e as páginas estão publicadas, Anderson.